Move /boot folder on reinstall?
I'm on Kubuntu 23.10 and will have to upgrade to 24.04 soon. I also have a partiton with Windows on it and I'd like to resize some space from there for my Linux partition. This is what my disk looks like:

I'm pretty sure the /boot partition shouldn't be moved since grub needs to know exactly where it is to work correctly. Since I'm gonna reinstall anyway do you think I can do this resizing?

I can't see why you cannot do it...  I've not attempted what you are doing (not for /boot; but I have for other directories) and haven't encountered issues.  You didn't mention what type of install you're planning on doing (clean? unclean? etc) but I'd still expect a pretty good unclean install, clean of course I'd expect perfect.

To achieve what you want, you will need to move the root (n1p5) and the system partition (n1p7) more to the front. Then it will be possible to increase the size of root partition n1p7.
In principle, you can resize and move partitions before installation using a disk partitioning program like gparted or Gnome Disks. While resizing is fast, moving large partitions can be a lengthy process, and there is some chance it does not succeed. Be advised if you attempt that, and, more importantly, make sure you have an up-to-date backup of all your personal data.
Repartitioning can be done independently before installation (gparted, Gnome Disks), but can also be performed from within the installer through the "Custom" option. In principle, you need to

Reduce the size of the windows partition n1p4
Move the boot partition n1p5 to occupy the space freed by reducing n1p4 (may be slow)
Delete the swap partition n1p6 or also move it forwards (may be slow again). You can have a new swap partition created
Move the system partition n1p7 forwards (this certainly will be slow)
Increase the system partition n1p7. If you deleted the swap partition in step 5, leave some space for a new swap partition.
(Optional) Create a new swap partition.

After this, you will need to run the Ubuntu installer in "Custom" mode. You must manually assign how partitions are used. By default, the installer will place a checkbox next to "format". Make sure to uncheck this box for the system partition, else the existing system and data will be erased.
- nvme0n1p1 - vfat - /boot/efi [x] format
- nvme0n1p5 - ext4 - /boot/efi [x] format
- nvme0n1p6 - ext4 - /         [] format 

If you keep a swap:
- nvme0n1p7 - swap - 

Many desktop linux distributions do not anymore implement a dedicated swap partition. They work with a swap file instead. The only reason you may prefer a swap partition is if you use hibernation (this is not the same as "suspend"). Hibernation quite commonly does not work properly with linux so is actually disabled by default in many linux distribution.
Recommendation: fresh install
A fresh install now and then is good. Now that you want to rearrange partitions, this may be a good moment. The procedure will be more simple: with a partition editor, erase partitions n1p5 and up. Then in the installer, select "Use free space" to have a fully automatic installation in the free space.

You can decide on the partition layout you want, then boot your install medium in "Try Ubuntu" mode.
Be sure that none of the discs's partitions is in use. This includes swap, use sudo swapon -v to see what is in use. Use sudo swapoff [partition] to release swap on any disc you plan to modify.
Run gparted Be very careful to select the correct disc in gparted's upper right corner. You can destroy your system if you do this wrong!
Use gparted to impose the partitioning scheme on the new disc. Use GPT, not MBR. gparted accumulates your partitioning commands to give you a chance to review them. Take advantage of this opportunity.
Click confirm, and wait until gparted finishes.
Reboot your install medium, and choose "Advanced"->"Something else".
This install flavor will let you specify which partitions are which.
Along the left edge of the window, there is a checkbox for each filesystem, the column is titled "Format". UNCHECK every of the filesystems that you want to keep. For new, partitions (on the new disc), leave the box checked.
Check your work.
Enjoy!
